# Clojure getting a page from a website as html

Tags: clojure

Whats the best way to get a page from a website, and handling 404 redirects within clojure.

I've used enlive, but it automatically transforming the page, which I do not want as I want to store the HTML in a DB for future reference.

```
(defn fetch-page [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))
```

I've came across `slurp` to get raw html content, but I don't know if this is the best method to retrieve things from external websites.

The second issue I have is handling 404, what is the best way to handle it, my clojure program ungracefully exists when it encounters a 404.

Code:

```
(println (slurp "http://www.google.com/doesnotexists.html"))
```

Output:

> CompilerException java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com/doesnotexists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 isn't a redirect, it indicates "Not found".  But regardless, you can handle the exception the same way you handle any exception in Clojure ... with `try`/`catch`:

```
(try
  (slurp "http://www.google.com/doesnotexists.html")
  (catch java.io.FileNotFoundException ex
    <handle exception...>))
```